# With LinqtoSql, when/how does it map your objects to tables?

Tags: linq-to-sql

With LINQ To SQL, how/when does the process map your object/entity to your table?

Does it create its own ADO.NET code under the hood? Is it strongly typed?

Are the SQL parameters taking column size/type into account? (nvarchar 500, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot look at my current project but you could create a sample DBML file and look what it's doing under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the DBML file, it generates standard .NET classes that are marked up with attributes.  It is strongly-typed, and respects foreign-key constraints.